# spoof $session['xyz']

Tags: php

I am evalating a way to secure PHP pages. I wonder if someone can provide me a code to spoof by sending a fake referer to $_session['xyz'] in main.php?

Do I have to know the session variable before I could sent a spoof value?

So far I tried my code below.

```
    <?php
header("Referer: http://domain.com.sg");
$host = "domain.com.sg"; 
$file = "demo.php";

$hdrs = array( 'http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header'=> "accept-language: en\r\n" . 
        "Host: $host\r\n" .
        "Referer: http://$host\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($hdrs);
$fp = fopen("http://domain.com.sg/dem251.php", 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is relation between referer and session?

Answer (score 3):

Session values are kept server-side. Unless your PHP has [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) enabled, the only way a remote user could directly set something in the session is via your code. So if you don't have something like:

```
$_SESSION['xyz'] = $_GET['xyz'];
```

anywhere, then it's "safe".

As for the referer itself, that's just an HTTP header, which is COMPLETELY under control of the user. It's best to ignore the referer completely, or at least treat it as you would toxic waste.

Comment: even if the session value is $_Server[] or using referer?

Comment: Read up about register globals - it's the only way to automatically pollute a script with externally defined variables. If it's off, then the only way any user-provided data gets into PHP variables (other than the GET/POST/REQUEST/COOKIE superglobals) is if YOU or one of your libraries/modules does it.

Comment: One caveat:  A user can cause the session values to be populated with those present in a given session if they can obtain the session ID.  So one user can take another's session, although they can't arbitrarily manipulate the session-variable values.

Comment: That great, I tried var_export($_SESSION); and the server return NULL. I suppose the register globals is OFF and that would prevent hacker from spoof or hijack session in anyway?

Comment: Session hijacking has nothing to do with register globals. A hijack is some user X somehow managing to get user Z's session cookie ID and using it for their own purposes. A null $_SESSION probably means a session hasn't been started yet (eg. no call to `session_start()`.

Comment: I see, I got array() and that because I did not use session_register() and it was discourage.